# comparing the last line of a dataframe with a row above it and another row above it again

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe where on the same column, many rows of data exist.
I need to compare the last (newest row) with the row above it (2nd last row), and the row above it again (3rd last row)

the code is as follows :

```
dataframe.loc[
        (
            # Scontents : data value is above 70
            (qtpylib.crossed_above(dataframe['avg'], self.sell_avg.value)) &
            (dataframe['tema'] > dataframe['bb_middleband']) &  # Guard: tema above BB middle
            #Compare here :
            (dataframe['tema'] < dataframe['tema'].shift(1))
        ),
        'execute02'] = 1
return dataframe
```

this piece can compare last row and the row above it.

i tried :

```
(dataframe['tema'] < dataframe['tema'].shift(1) < dataframe['tema'].shift(1))
```

but it give me value error in shell :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm very Noob with panda...what should I do so I can compare 3 instances? I tried reading the panda doc but it just tells about index =1 but I don't know how to tell it to read 3 rows up from last row.

Thank You.

Kris

Comment: `< dataframe['tema'].shift(1) < dataframe['tema'].shift(1)` doesn't make any sense. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes I'm sorry, I meant ```.shift(2)``` on the last part

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iloc` for this, indexing with negative values counts from the last row.

For example `iloc[-1]` gives you the last column, `-2` gives the column above it and so on.

So the code becomes:

```
((dataframe['tema'].iloc[-1] < dataframe['tema'].iloc[-2]) &
(dataframe['tema'].iloc[-1] < dataframe['tema'].iloc[-3]))
```

Comment: yes this will work, however I'm prevented to use `iloc` since I cannot use absolute position address on the rows of data,
the latest rows are constantly updated every 5 seconds, until clock pass the 5 minute, then a new row will be made (it's a data stream from stock market).
so we must look to the last stable rows which is the row above it.
in between row updating 'iloc' would have been fine, but the values themselves keep changing so it'd be unusable, and once it updates there will be some sort of "jump" that cause all kinds of red things popping up

Answer (score 0):

this should solve the issue

if (dftemp['close'].iloc[0] > dftemp['VWAP'].iloc[-1]):
print('price is above vwap',dftemp['close'].iloc[0],dftemp['VWAP'].iloc[-1])